# SSIS File Move/Copy

Tags: file, ssis, scripting

I am at a complete loss on this one.  I am attempting to move/copy files from one location to another.  I have the file names in variables, but the source and destination directories are not (although I could do that if absolutely necessary).  And when running this in a script task, I get nothing but exception errors that I cannot figure out for the life of me.  The code:

```
string ctlFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\nas01042pn\data\localcaredelivery\fileserver_dev\provider\load\", Dts.Variables["User::str_CTLFileName"].Value.ToString());
string ctlDest = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\nas01042pn\data\localcaredelivery\fileserver_dev\provider\archive\", Dts.Variables["User::str_CTLFileName"].Value.ToString());
string txtFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\nas01042pn\data\localcaredelivery\fileserver_dev\provider\load\", Dts.Variables["User::str_TXTFileName"].Value.ToString());
string txtDest = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\nas01042pn\data\localcaredelivery\fileserver_dev\provider\archive\", Dts.Variables["User::str_TXTFileName"].Value.ToString());

System.IO.File.Copy(ctlFile, ctlDest, true);
System.IO.File.Copy(txtFile, txtDest, true);

System.IO.File.Delete(ctlFile);
System.IO.File.Delete(txtFile);
```

And as stated, I get the following exception error every time I run this:

Inbound file names are valid.  Source and destination directories are valid.  What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing in this that is preventing me from moving/copying the files?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ORQd.png)

Comment: What's wrong with using the built-in `File System Task`?

Comment: I cannot find a tutorial or anything online about File System Task that deals with dynamic file names outside of using the foreach loop.  Every time this task fires, I have 2 specific named files in variables that need to be moved/copied; I don't need a foreach loop for this.  If I could get my hands on a solid tutorial for using the file system task to move 2 files from the source folder to a destination folder using the 2 variables I have, great.  Until then, I'm stuck with trying to script, and as of yet, I'm unable to figure this out.

Comment: In the configuration of the `File System Task` you can specify if the source or destination paths are contained in variables.

Comment: Googling "SSIS File System Task Variable" pulled up this as the second result, after the BOL entry: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/file-system-task-in-ssis/

Comment: Not only screenshots of the file system task but if you install BimlExpress, you can run the code https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/02/biml-file-system-task.html

Comment: The file name is contained in a variable, but the file path is not.  And I have 2 source files, not one, so defining a variable for file system task is not going to work here.

Comment: You have two files? Create two `File System Tasks`. Your file name is in a variable and your path isn't? Where does the path come from? If it's always static, you can create a new variable whose value is [path] + [filename variable value], then use THAT variable in the `File System Task`.